# Adding custom expensive field on Django model serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Normally, in Django, using rest_framework, to add a custom field to a model, you can use `SerializerMethodField`. From what I understand however, this works great for values that are easy to calculate, but if the value requires database queries to related tables, you're going to be performing these for every item being returned.

If I have a ViewSet like this:

```py
class ProductViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ProductSerializer
    ...
```

And a Serializer like this:

```py
class ProductSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Product
        fields = "__all__"
```

How do I run a bulk query to get some data from a related table for all the products being serialized, and attach it to a new field?

Ex: if each product is attached to an `Order`, maybe I want to add an `order_number` field. I could do this:

```py
class ProductSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    order_number = SerializerMethodField()

    @staticmethod
    def get_order_number(obj):
        return obj.order.order_number

    class Meta:
        model = models.Product
        fields = "__all__"
```

But if the view is returning 100 products, that will be 100 database queries. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a better way to do it, but one way I recently found is to do this:

```py
class ProductViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ProductSerializer
    ...

    def _add_fields(data):
        # Add extra fields to data
        ...

        # Return data
        return data

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            data = serializer.data
            data = self._add_fields(data)
            return self.get_paginated_response(data)
        else:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
            data = serializer.data
            data = self._add_fields(data)
            Response(data)
```

This is overriding the `list` method that the ViewSet inherits from `rest_framework.mixins.ListModelMixin`, but before it is converted into a response, it is sent to `self._add_fields()` to be processed, where you can add additional, last-minute fields to it. There, you can run django db queries, and they will only be run once - not once per model.

This way, you can also look at `request.query_params`, allowing you to use query parameters to only add the expensive embedded fields on each model if the request specifically asks for it.